# Scala generic type in trait

Tags: scala, generics

What I am trying to do :

```
trait BasicModel {
  type U <: BasicModel

  def -(that: U): BasicModel
  ...
}

class MatrixFactorizationModel(val W: DenseMatrix[Double], val b: Double) extends  BasicModel {
  type U = MatrixFactorizationModel

  def -(that: MatrixFactorizationModel): MatrixFactorizationModel =  new MatrixFactorizationModel(W + that.W, b - that.b)
  ...
}

abstract class SAG [T <: BasicModel#U : ClassTag] {
  //type T <: BasicModel#U    I also tried like that

  def modelDerivative(idx: Index, cstDerivative: Double): T

  def compute(): T = {
    SumDerivative = SumDerivative - modelDerivative(idx, Hist(idx))
  }
}
```

When compute is call I got this error :

```
type mismatch;
found   : T
required: _129.U where val _129: T
    SumDerivative = SumDerivative - modelDerivative(idx, Hist(idx))
```

I don't understand why this is not working because T is a BasicModel#U. Could someone explain me, and give me an alternative?

---

EDIT :

I also changed in SAG T <: BasicModel#u in T <: BasicModel and when I use T to change it in T#U  :

```
abstract class SAG [T <: BasicModel : ClassTag] extends Optimizer {

  def modelDerivative(idx: Index, cstDerivative: Double): T#U

   ...
}
```

But :

```
type mismatch;
found   : T#U
required: _128.U where val _128: T#U
    SumDerivative = SumDerivative - modelDerivative(idx, Hist(idx))
```

Comment: the matrixfactorization and "optimizer" don't seem related to your question, might be clearer to simplify to the smallest possible example of the issue.

Comment: oh, I see it's the implementation of BasicModel...

Comment: Sorry, I remove the "extend optimiser" but I let the MatrixFactorisation because in the SAG, I am trying to subtract instances of MatrixFactorisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's sort of like the type defined in BasicModel, U, is a member of an instance of BasicModel.  It's like the difference between static/instance variables in Java.  To match a type definition, you need the exact same type.  If it were static, you couldn't override it in the subclass, MatrixFactorizationModel.

`T <: BasicModel` in SAG represents *any* T <: BasicModel#U (the parent #U) where that #U could be any subtype of BasicModel.  Even though you might happen to have specified MatrixFactorizationModel wherever you instantiated an instance of SAG, the compiler doesn't know what specific T you have in this context, or that it's a subtype of the same U.

You might have better luck with something like `trait BasicModel { def [T<:BasicModel]-(that:T):T }`.  It's a bit more verbose, and can be a real pain if you've got a lot of method signatures to type, but sometimes signatures like that work out better.

Comment: Thanks, I get it when you say "T <: BasicModel#U (the parent #U) where that #U could be any subtype of BasicModel". So I tried another solution where instead I do ""T <: BasicModel" and T#U when I use it. Kind of the same error I put it in my post.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion but doesn't work either.
(so, I will try to do some implicit convert somewhere)

Comment: how is SumDerivative defined?  Unless it's defined inside SAG, there's no way to even specify a SumDerivative of a type that matches the type T specified *only* in SAG.  Beware that `SAG[T<:BasicModel#U]` means *any* type that is a subtype of the `type U`, where that `U` could be defined in any subclass of BasicModel... not necessarily the same BasicModel used to define SumDerivative.

Comment: what I'm suggesting is something like:
`trait BasicModel[T]{ def -(that:T):T }`, `class MyModel extends BasicModel[MyModel]{ def -(that:MyModel):MyModel=that }`, and `abstract class Foo[T<:BasicModel[T]] { val instance:T;  def foo(that:T):T=that - instance }`